# Scanf c++ on a string

Tags: c++

I have been looking and I have not found anything on scanf that really helps me. I am completly new to this and was hoping for help on reading a string with scanf. The first thre numbers can be any digits. I was attempting to read them into a variable int. the last one in the string is a char. this is my string

```
(1,2,123, 0)
(1,2,1,s)
```

This is my code:

```
int i,j,k;
char c, final;

scanf ("%c", c, "%d",&i, "%c", c, "%d", &j, "%d",&k, "%c", final);
```

I know this is not right but any help is appreciated

Comment: You googled for "scanf" and found nothing useful?? Seriously?

Comment: The 1st place to go is probably the documentation: [`scanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)

Comment: Troll?? .............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the first 3 are digits and the last one is a character and are seperated by a space,which you want to assign to 3 integer variables and a character variable, use `scanf` like this:

```
int a,b,c;
char ch; 
scanf ("%d%d%d %c",&a,&b,&c,&ch);
```

Or else if you want to extract 3 integers and a character from a string , use `sscanf`. It is not possible to do it with `scanf`.